# Eslint and start webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, eslint

I would like to run eslint before webpack start.
I installed parallel and npm-run-all packages but didn't help.
When I type: **npm run dev** I get:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! myproject-ui@1.0.0
>   eslint: `eslint src/` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
>   at the myproject-ui@1.0.0 eslint script. npm ERR! This is probably not
>   a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./tests/**/*.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "code:coverage": "nyc npm run test",
    "eslint": "eslint src/",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel start eslint"
  },
```

Any idea how to run eslint and webpack parallel?;)

Greetings

Comment: do the commands `npm start` and `npm run eslint` run successfully on their own?

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant solution but works fine

```
    "lint": "eslint src || exit 0",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel lint start"
```

Because link returns exit 1 err so it makes them work parallel even though ;).